# Servlet processing exception

Tags: java, servlets, jena

A newbie user question. I have defined a class like this:
...

```
    public class ConceitosSelecionados implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String conceitoInicial;
        private String conceitoFinal;

        // Construtor -----------------------------------
        public ConceitosSelecionados() {

        }

        public ConceitosSelecionados(String conceitoInicial, String conceitoFinal) {

            this.conceitoInicial = conceitoInicial;
            this.conceitoFinal = conceitoFinal;
        }

// Getters & Setters ---------------
    public String getConceitoInicial(){return conceitoInicial};
    public String getConceitoFinal(){return conceitoFinal};
    public void setConceitoInicial(String conceitoInicial){this.conceitoInicial = conceitoInicial};
    public void setConceitoFinal(String conceitoFinal){this.conceitoFinal = conceitoFinal};
```

This class to get user imputs comming from a webApp. So I set a form  SelecionaConceitosForm to collect user inputs, the code snippet is this:
...

```
public ConceitosSelecionados selecaoUsuario(HttpServletRequest request) {

        ConceitosSelecionados conceitosSelecionados = new ConceitosSelecionados();

        try {
            processaSelecaoConceitoInicial(request, conceitosSelecionados);
            processaSelecaoConceitoFinal(request, conceitosSelecionados);

            if (isSucces()) {

                setError(FIELD_RESULTADO, "Seleção dos conceitos realizada!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conceitosSelecionados;
    }
```

...
which is to be processed by a servlet...
{...}

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Prepara o formBean

        SelecionaConceitosForm selecionaConceitosForm = new SelecionaConceitosForm(
                conceitosSelecionados);
        request.setAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_FORM, selecionaConceitosForm);

        // Processa a solicitação e obtém os resultados
        ConceitosSelecionados conceitosSelecionados = new ConceitosSelecionados();
        conceitosSelecionados = selecionaConceitosForm.selecaoUsuario(request);
        request.setAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_SELECTED, conceitosSelecionados);

        String destino = "/GeraSequenciaServlet";
        request.getRequestDispatcher(destino).include(request, response);

    }
```

these are to be processed in order to be submitted to a Jena application, as I try to process, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field conceitoFinal
```

Answer (score 3):

The exception means that somewhere in your code you are doing something like

```
ConceitosSelecionados.conceitoFinal
```

i.e. you are trying to access `conceitoFinal` on the class directly, not on an instance of your class.